# How to upload multiple images at once using cloudinary and lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, cloudinary

I wrote a code in Lumen to upload multiple images at once using cloudinary, but the code doesn't work only the first image gets uploaded.

```
$images = $request->file('picture');
        $uploaded = [];
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            error_log('for statement fires.');
            Cloudder::upload($image, null, [
                'folder' => '/dog-lovers',
                'discard_original_filename' => true,
            ]);
            $image_uploaded = Cloudder::getResult();
            array_push($uploaded, $image_uploaded['url']);

        }
        return array('message'=>'successful', 'file_url'=>$uploaded);
```

In the above code, the for statement doesn't get called, because $images isn't an array i guess, so I made $images an array

```
    $images[] = $request->file('picture');
```

Now the for statement fires up, but only the first selected image from postman gets uploaded

this is a screenshot from my postman just in case anyone is wondering how i'm uploading via postman

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why the other 4 images don't get uploaded and how to fix this?

Comment: Does `$request->file('picture')` contain 5  `UploadedFile` objects? If not you are probably sending the files wrong.

Comment: @Remul  no it doesn't, which is what the problem is, but I have no idea why they aren't uploading, what do you think the right way may be?

Comment: @Remul you were right i was sending the picture wrongly, i solved it by adding `picture[]` to postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution to this is to make the picture parameter on postman an array, like this `picture[]`

decided to post the solution incase anyone ran into similar problems